# cant insert into a table in php,values retrieved form url

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making an e-commerce website as a semester project, and while trying to insert values into a table. I have a table with 5 columns, the first one being a primary key that auto increments.When i try to insert,it inserts values in the second column while leaving the next two blank and inserting 0 in the fifth column. I tried echoing the values on the page to check if they are being retrieved through the url, and they work. It also shows no error.I've highlighted the section where i have a problem.
my table:

[image]

**Here's the entire code Code.it's sort of a bill that shows all the customer details an the products he purchased.:**

```
    <!--Starting session-->
<?php
    session_start();
    include "adam.php";
?>
<!--Cart session from sign up page hidden fields in login form and sign up form-->
<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);//will stop displaying notice errors
    $cartoutput="";
    $carttotal="";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"])|| count($_SESSION["cart_array"])<1){
        $cartoutput="<h2 align='center' style='color:#ea6a53;'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";       }
    else{
        $i=0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $each_item){

            $item_id=$each_item['item_id'];
            $quantity=$each_item['quantity'];
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $product_name=$row['product_name'];
                $product_cost=$row['price'];
                $product_details=$row['details'];
            }
            $product_total_cost=$product_cost * $quantity;
            $carttotal=$product_total_cost+$carttotal;
            //Dynamically render table rows 
            //product name is a link to product page
            $cartoutput.='<tr>
                        <td><a href="prodpage.php?id='.$item_id.'">' . $product_name . '</a></td>
                        <td>'.$product_details.'</td>
                        <td>Rs.&nbsp;'.$product_cost.'</td>
                        <td>'.$each_item['quantity'].'</td>
                        <td>Rs.&nbsp;'.$product_total_cost.'</td>
                        </tr>';
                $i++;
            }
            $carttotal="<strong>Cart Total:</strong>&nbsp;<span style='color:black;'>Rs.&nbsp;".$carttotal."</span>";
        }
?>
<!--retrieving user session from last page.php-->
<?php
      $cust_id=$_SESSION['id'];
      $username=$_SESSION['username'];
      $password=$_SESSION['password'];
?>
<!--retrieving shipping,payment cardno variables from url passed from last page.php-->
<?php   
    if(isset($_GET['payment'])){
        global $payment_type,$shipping_type,$card_no;
        $payment_type=$_GET['payment'];
        $shipping_type=$_GET['shipping'];
        $card_no=$_GET['cardno'];
        }
?>
<!--Retrieveing customer information for display-->
<?php   
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='$cust_id' LIMIT 1");
    $row_count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($row_count>0){
        while($row_count=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $username=$row_count['username'];
            $email=$row_count['emailid'];
            $mobile_no=$row_count['mobileno'];
            $address=$row_count['address'];
            $user_display='<tr>
                        <td>'.$username.'</td>
                        <td>'.$email.'</td>
                        <td>'.$mobile_no.'</td>
                        <td>'.$address.'</td>
                        </tr>';
            }
        }
?>
<!--Inserting all data in transaction,shipping_payment_details db on confirm button click-->
<?php 
    ***if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shipping_payment_details(customer_id,payment_type,shipping_type,card_no) VALUES('$cust_id','$payment_type','$shipping_type','$card_no')") or die(mysql_error());***
        $sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions(customer_id,transaction_status)VALUES('$cust_id',1)") or die(mysql_error());    
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $each_item){
            $item_id=$each_item['item_id'];
            $quantity=$each_item['quantity'];
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $stock=$row["stock"];
            }
            $stock=$stock-$quantity;
            $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE products SET stock='$stock' WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        header("location:feedback.php");
        }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Confirmation Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tlfcss.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale-1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login Form.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/product_display_css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="big_wrapper">  
           <header id="topheader">          
                <!--Logo and menu bar php file-->
               <?php include_once "scripts/header file.php"?>
            </header>
            <section>


                 <div style="margin-left:24px;font-size:14px;font-family:Segoe UI;text-align:left;">
                    <h2 style="color:#ea6a53;margin-top:20px;" align="center">Confirmation page</h2>

                    <!--Customer table display-->
                    <h4 style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:14px;color:#2d2d2d;margin-top:10px;" align="center">Customer Information</h4>
                    <table width="881" height="78" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" dir="ltr" id="table" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:13px;text-align:center;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="196" height="23" align="center"><strong>Username</strong></td>
                          <td width="244" align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
                          <td width="166" align="center"><strong>Mobile No</strong></td>
                          <td width="231" align="center"><strong>Address</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php echo $user_display; ?>
                     </table>

                    <!--Cart display-->
                    <h4 style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:14px;color:#2d2d2d;margin-top:24px;" align="center">Your Cart</h4>
                      <table width="881" height="78" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" dir="ltr" id="table" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:13px;text-align:center;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="158" height="23" align="center"><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
                          <td width="305" align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                          <td width="82" align="center"><strong>Price</strong></td>
                          <td width="118" align="center"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
                          <td width="107" align="center"><strong>Total </strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <p><?php echo $cartoutput;?></p>
                      </table>
                <p align="right" style="margin-right:42px;margin-top:8px;color:#ea6a53"><?php echo $carttotal ?></p>

                <!--Shipping output-->
                <h4 style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:14px;color:#2d2d2d;margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:10px;" align="center">Shipping and Payment Details</h4>
                <p style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:14px;margin-left:15px;"><strong>Payment type:</strong>&nbsp;<?php echo  $payment_type; ?></p><br>
                <p style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:14px;margin-left:15px;"><strong>Shipping type:</strong>&nbsp;<?php echo  $shipping_type; ?></p><br>
                <p style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:14px;margin-left:15px;"><strong>Card No.:</strong>&nbsp;<?php echo  $card_no;?></p><br>
<form action="Final page.php" method="post" name="f1" target="_self">

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="proceed_button" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></form>
            </section>

            <?php include_once "scripts/customer footer.php"?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are learning MySQL and php, you shouldn't be using deprecated functionality like "mysql_" and you should be learning to make the code SQL-injection-attack-proof.

Comment: Seems like you are mixing `$_GET` and `$_POST`.. My comment may be a false positive if you are passing those three params via URL.`

Comment: Whats the back tick at the end?

Comment: I dont have enough reputation points so,stack won't let me upload photos.Here's a link to my table:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B04Apd4ZlD6_TFUwbVZBMThJSkE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: my url looks somewhat like this: Final%20page.php?payment=Credit%20Card&shipping=Normal&cardno=7897  and ignore the back tick,its just a typing mistake..

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I dont get any errors. THe insert statement inserts customer id,leaves payment_details and shipping_details columns blank and puts a 0 in card_no.

Comment: Remove the quotes for $card_no

Comment: Probably you're passing blank values.  Always concatenate your select statement into a string variable before passing to mysql_query (or PDO preferred).  Then you can output the statement for debugging.  Also, it's very dangerous not to mysql_escape_string() first, especially when values are coming from the URL querystring.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have missed a space before `VALUES` in your query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shipping_payment_details(customer_id,payment_type,shipping_type,card_no)VALUES('$cust_id','$payment_type','$shipping_type','$card_no')") or die(mysql_error());
```

should be:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shipping_payment_details(customer_id,payment_type,shipping_type,card_no) VALUES('$cust_id','$payment_type','$shipping_type','$card_no')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Still not working.I tried putting spaces and everything and even tried referencing w3schools for mysql insert syntax.Can't figure out what the problem is!!

Comment: It's actually a small part of a large code.It's quite big.The rest works fine,this is the only part that doesn't.